# bind(this) in ReactComponent.render() method

Tags: reactjs

I have a quite big `React.Component` with more than ten `bind(this)` calls in its constructor.

I don't think `.bind(this)` in a constructor gives any help to understand my code especially when reading the code inside of render().

So, I came up with the following idea, however, do not find how to achieve this.

```js
render() {
    if (this.methodToBind.getThis() === this) {
        this.methodToBind = this.methodToBind.bind(this);
    }
}
```

1. Is there any possible way I can get this of a method (`getThis()` from the example above)?
2. If yes for the above, is it a good practice to do this?

Comment: Will you please clarify, are you trying to check to see if the function has already had bind() called on it in the render? Or are you trying to use bind in the render?

Comment: Oh, my original intention was to use bind in the render() method because the relevant code should group together.

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer for you. I hope it helps. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Where to Bind This?**

When you create a function in a *Class Based Component* in *React.js* you must bind `this` in order to call it from the render method. Otherwise the function will not be in **scope**.

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Never `bind this` in the render method. Binding `this` in the render method will cause React to create a new function every time your Component is rerendered. This is why we most commonly bind in the constructor.
2. Bind in the constructor. By binding in the constructor, you can call your function in the render method by using `this.FunctionName();`

***Example Bind This***

```
    Class MyClass extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.FunctionName = this.FunctionName.bind(this);
    }

   myFunc () {
    // code here 
   }

    render() {
       this.FunctionName();
      return(
       <div>
        ...
       </div>
    );
    }
    }
```

3. User fat arrow functions instead of traditional function definitions. Fat arrow functions lexically bind the `this` value. So you do not have to add bind to the function in the constructor when you use the fat arrow function in the class.

*Important* - Fat arrow functions are not always available to use in a React class. Depending on how you setup React. You might have to install,

```
babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

Then add it to your `.bablerc` file like this,

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

**Example Fat Arrow**

```
 Class MyClass extends Component {

   myFunc = () => {
    // code here
   }

    render() {
       this.FunctionName();
      return(
       <div>
        ...
       </div>
    );
    }
    }
```

**Summary**

- Never bind a function in the render.
- Always bind in the constructor when using a traditional function
- *this* is automatically available on the function when using a fat arrow function.

Answer (score 5):

rather then doing this,

```
constructor () {
  super();
  this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
}

myFunc () {
  // code here
}
```

You can do something like this.

```
constructor () {
  super();
  // leave the binding, it's just not what the cool kids do these days
}

myFunc = () => {
  // see what I did here with = () => {} 
  // this will bind your `this` with it's parent 
  // lexical context, which is your class itself, cool right. Do this!
}
```

For a reference have a look at the MDN documentation for [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Oh, last time I checked, this es7 class property was just a proposal. It seems that it is not finalized. Thanks! I'll go for this!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure.

I am usually doing something like this:

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

or:

```
onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}
```

Comment: Isn't the first option to create new function method every time it renders? According to the official documentation `.bind()` returns new function every time it gets called.

Comment: Right, but the performance implications are unlikely to be noticeable